# Show A Div Section From A Selected Option - Stateless Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Am a bit new to react and redux. I am trying to call/show a section after a specific option value has been selected by a user. This select will be populated via an API (I can handle that), but for now, For example, if I have the below code

```
const Student = ({key}) = > {
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <div>
            <select>
                <option value="markJ">Mark J.</option>
                <option value="maryA">Marry A.</option>
                <option value="peterM">Peter M</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div id="showThisDiv">
            <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
         </div>
      </React.Fragment>

  );
};
export default Student
```

For example, if I want to show the div with id #showThisDiv after the option with a value of maryA has been selected, how would I accomplish that? I am trying to do this only in functional component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the state for store the selected option. When state value is maryA, then to show `showThisDiv`. It’s not necessary to use `id="showThisDiv"`.

```
const Student = ({key}) = > {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState()

  const handleChange = (event) => {
     setSelected(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <div>
            <select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="markJ">Mark J.</option>
                <option value="maryA">Marry A.</option>
                <option value="peterM">Peter M</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         {selected === 'maryA' && <div id="showThisDiv">
            <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
         </div>}
      </React.Fragment>

  );
};
export default Student
```

If you need the **multiple** select, you can use the next code:

```
  const Student = ({key}) = > {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState()

  const handleChange = (event) => {
     const newSelectedOptions = [...event.target.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value);
     setSelected(newSelectedOptions)
  }

  return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <div>
            <select value={selected} onChange={handleChange} multiple>
                <option value="markJ">Mark J.</option>
                <option value="maryA">Marry A.</option>
                <option value="peterM">Peter M</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         {selected.includes("maryA") && <div id="showThisDiv">
            <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
         </div>}
      </React.Fragment>

  );
};
export default Student
```